# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell', but actually returning twice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to set up a table view that will change cells based on the segmented controller at the top. However, in attempting to change the cells when reloading the tableview, I am receiving a return function error when in fact I have a return function. What can I do to fix this?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {




    if friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("0")

        cell = self.friendsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsTableViewCell


        cell.nameLabel.text = friends[indexPath.row]
        cell.bacLabel.text = String(friendsBac[indexPath.row])
        cell.statusImageView.image = friendsImage[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    if friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        print("1")

        celladd = self.friendsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celladd", for: indexPath) as! FriendsAddTableViewCell

        celladd.nameLabel.text = requested[indexPath.row]
        celladd.statusImageView.image = UIImage(named: "greenlight")

        return celladd


    }

}
```

[image: View of the Table With Two different Custom UITableViewCells]

Comment: The method is not returning anything if your both conditions are not satisfying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return a cell. In the above code, if both conditions failed, then nothing will be returned. So a warning raised. Just remove second "if" condition and use else case as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("0")

        cell = self.friendsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsTableViewCell


        cell.nameLabel.text = friends[indexPath.row]
        cell.bacLabel.text = String(friendsBac[indexPath.row])
        cell.statusImageView.image = friendsImage[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    else {
        print("1")

        celladd = self.friendsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celladd", for: indexPath) as! FriendsAddTableViewCell

        celladd.nameLabel.text = requested[indexPath.row]
        celladd.statusImageView.image = UIImage(named: "greenlight")

        return celladd


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: If using a `switch` statement make sure every case returns a cell and that the `default` case either returns a cell or triggers an error.

Answer (score 5):

You have two if statements which both could potentially not be true, so you must return a cell in the case that the selected index is neither 0 or 1.

```
if friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    ...
    return cell
}
else if friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    ...
    return celladd
}
return UITableViewCell()
```

I prefer to use switch statements for this kind of thing.

```
switch friendSelector.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    ...
    return cell
case 1:
    ...
    return celladd
default:
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very obvious. You have two return statements in two if conditions. What if both your 'if' conditions do not get executed? There is no return statement for that case. That's why the compiler is complaining